# How to get page ID from wiki data API using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-api

With the following query I get all the tourist attractions near me with SPARQL using the Wiki Data API. What I can't get to work is: I also need the page ID for each result. The page ID is the unique ID that an article has on every wikipedia page. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben has page ID: `7290308` in the english wikipedia.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?image ?itemCoordinates ?description ?wikipediaLink ?wikipediaID WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:around {
    ?item wdt:P625 ?itemCoordinates .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:center "Point(9.2478 48.9929)"^^geo:wktLiteral .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "5" .
  }
 FILTER (
  EXISTS { ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q570116 } # Tourist attractions
)
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?image }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item schema:description ?description .
    FILTER(LANG(?description) = "de")
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?wikipediaLink schema:about ?item ;
                   schema:isPartOf <https://de.wikipedia.org/> .
  }
  FILTER EXISTS { 
    ?wikipediaLink schema:about ?item ;
                   schema:isPartOf <https://de.wikipedia.org/> .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". }
}
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 0
```

How do I get the page ID? The URL is good but doesn't include the ID..

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think the wikipedia page id is stored on wikidata. Consequently I don't think you can get everything you want in one call, but you can pass the titles to https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles= and get the ids that way.

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI may be an option but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: `SELECT ?pageid WHERE {
   <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Ben> schema:about ?item 
  ; schema:name ?name ;
      schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> 
     SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "en.wikipedia.org" .
         bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "Generator" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:generator "allpages" .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapfrom ?name .
         bd:serviceParam mwapi:gapto ?name .
         ?pageid wikibase:apiOutput "@pageid" .
    }
}`